# Will an Android phone still use data when cellular data is switched off?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I refer to the option under Settings / Data Usage. If that is turned off is there a possibility for the system to still use mobile data?

Comment: Of data will still be enabled when it is disabled in settings, than what is purpose of switching on and off. There is chance to some app is able to turn on data but that must be mentioned in app description otherwise app won't be on play store, and it's considered as kind of malware

Comment: No that is what the setting is for.  If its a kids device I would advise a network wise data block on the device.  There the device can't be tampered with or overrided with a root.

Answer (score 0):

> If that is turned off is there a possibility for the system to still use mobile data?

Absolutely not. That setting turns off the data completely as soon as you use it.

Sometimes it takes 2-3 seconds to turn the data off completely(the LTE/H+ sign to disappear because of network issues), else the data is always switched off immediately.

Comment: Just wondering what basis / reference you might have for this answer. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @user55570 Usually toggle buttons are to switch states such as on and off & their use is documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: I was particularly wondering does this switch prevent background data. Because there seems to be a separate switch for this.